# Deletando utilizando subquery e join

Tags: oracle, join, pl-sql, delete

Caros, estou iniciando no SQL e estou tendo uma dificuldade em fazer uma deleção utilizando subquery e join.

Criei uma tabela temporária `EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP` com 7000 linhas, eu preciso deletar uns registros da tabela `EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD`, mas só posso deletar os registros da tabela `EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD` desde de que os mesmos existam na tabela `EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP`, ou seja eu utilizei o comando `EXISTS` para isto.

Mas estou tendo problemas, pois a minha query esta trazendo mais de 7000 linhas. Preciso que minha query traga a mesma quantidade de linhas que a tabela temporária.
 Segue a query que estou utilizando:

```
Select distinct p.EVENT_ITEM_ID
  From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD p
 Inner Join EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t
    On t.EVENT_ITEM_ID = p.EVENT_ITEM_ID
 Where Exists (Select  t.EVENT_ITEM_ID
          From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t
         Where t.DYNAMIC_FIELD_ID In (39, 40));
```

PKs da tabela `EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD` :

- `EVENT_ITEM_ID`
- `EVENT_PLACE_ID`
- `COMMERCIAL_DYNAMIC_ID`
- `DYNAMIC_FIELD_ID`
- `LINE_NUMBER`

Comment: Qual o banco de dados você esta utilizando? E como você esta começando com SQL, procure usar nomes mais simples para as tabelas, assim você não se perde.

Comment: Estou usando o PLSQL para fazer isto.

Answer (score 0):

Em geral vc pode fazer **DELETE** e **UPDATE** usando joins sem problema.

Geralmente eu faço como vc, faço primeiro um **SELECT** retornando todos os registros que quero deletar:

```
Select distinct p.EVENT_ITEM_ID
 From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD p
 Inner Join EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t On t.EVENT_ITEM_ID = p.EVENT_ITEM_ID
Where Exists (Select t.EVENT_ITEM_ID From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t Where t.DYNAMIC_FIELD_ID In (39, 40));
```

Daqui fica fácil pois a diferença do **DELETE** é só tirar o **DISTINCT**:

```
delete p
 From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD p
 Inner Join EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t On t.EVENT_ITEM_ID = p.EVENT_ITEM_ID
Where Exists (Select t.EVENT_ITEM_ID From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t Where t.DYNAMIC_FIELD_ID In (39, 40));
```

**Obs 1:** Testado com TSQL já que o OP esqueceu de "taggear" o SGBD usado.

**Obs 2:** Verifique se seu **SELECT** está correto pois oq vai trazer a interseção das duas tabelas é o join. O filtro simplesmente vai verificar se deve retornar alguma coisa ou nada caso a **SUBQUERY** retorne algo ou nada

Comment: Olá Jean, 
Mas a query que eu uso acima está trazendo mais de 7000 linhas, creio que ficou em cartesioano e por isso esta vindo bastante registro.
Esta é a grande questão, como montar uma query que possa trazer a mesma quantidade de linha para eu ter a certeza que estou deletando os caras corretos.

Comment: @Leo Bem, isso é outra questão, além do mais vc está usando distinct, isso significa que vc não está mostrando registros duplicados e obviamente se vc quiser deletar todos vc tera que deletar as duplicatas, então depende do que vc quer fazer vc vai deletar muito mais do que vc está listando

Comment: @Leo talvez vc fosse + fácil se vc explicar sucintamente oq vc quer, usar um exemplo usando o [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ce83/2) dar um exemplo do resultado esperado, finalmente taggear qual SGBD vc está usando e aproveitar e ler o [help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Problema resolvido. Fiz da seguinte forma:

select p.* From PR_EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD p
 Where (p.EVENT_ITEM_ID, p.event_place_id, p.commercial_dynamic_id, p.dynamic_field_id, p.line_number)
   in  (Select t.EVENT_ITEM_ID, t.event_place_id, t.commercial_dynamic_id, t.dynamic_field_id, t.line_number
          From EVENT_ITEM_PLACE_DYN_FIELD_BKP t
         Where t.DYNAMIC_FIELD_ID In (39, 40)); 

Desta forma trouxe a mesma quantidade contida na tabela BPK, bastando alterar o select para delete.

Obrigado pelo apoio Jean